# Extracting Multiple Sublists from a List in R

Tags: r, list, extract, lapply

Another question regarding lists that I'm struggling to find a solution for. I am working with tracking data from DeepLabCut, using code called DLCAnalyzer (see code and find example data here: https://github.com/ETHZ-INS/DLCAnalyzer).

Here's sample code to give an idea of the hierarchal nesting structure of lists produced using this code:

```
`library(sp)         #tested with v1.3-2
library(imputeTS)   #tested with v3.0
library(ggplot2)    #tested with v3.1.0
library(ggmap)      #tested with v3.0.0
library(data.table) #tested with v1.12.8
library(cowplot)    #tested with v0.9.4
library(corrplot)   #tested with v0.84
library(keras)      #REQUIRES TENSORFLOW INSTALL. tested with v2.2.5.0

setwd("PathToDLCFolder") #from github link above
source('R/DLCAnalyzer_Functions_final.R')
input_folder <- "example/OFT/DLC_Data/"
files <- list.files(input_folder) 
pipeline <- function(path){
  Tracking <- ReadDLCDataFromCSV(path, fps = 25)
  Tracking <- CutTrackingData(Tracking,start = 100, end = 300)
  Tracking <- CalibrateTrackingData(Tracking, "area",in.metric = 42*42, points = c("tr","tl","bl","br"))
  Tracking <- CleanTrackingData(Tracking, likelihoodcutoff = 0.95)
  Tracking <- AddOFTZones(Tracking, scale_center = 0.5,scale_periphery  = 0.8 ,scale_corners = 0.4)
  Tracking <- OFTAnalysis(Tracking, movement_cutoff = 5, integration_period = 5, points = "bodycentre")
  return(Tracking)
}
TrackingAll <- RunPipeline(files,input_folder,FUN = pipeline) #This creates an example list of what I'm trying to work with. You can see it has multiple sublists`
```

I'm trying to create a new list with only some of this data. I want to pull out both `TrackingAll$'OFT_1.csv'$data$nose` (where nose is a sublist within data) AND `TrackingAll$'OFT_1.csv'$median.data` (median.data is a data frame).

I've successfully used lapply to extract the nose sublist and median.data sublists separately,
`nosedata <- lapply(TrackingAll, getElemeent, c("data", "nose"))` and
`meddata <- lapply(TrackingAll, getElement, "median.data")`
but if I try to do it all
`lapply(TrackingAll, getElement, c("data", "nose", "median.data"))`, then I just get NULL values.

I've also tried using "[", which works for pulling out the median data, but not for the nose data (pulls out all the data, not just nose.

Because of how complicated this list is (and my lack of knowledge on using lists, I don't know how to make a more reproducible example than just directing you to the original code source (which should let you fully replicate this dataset). However, here are also some screenshots that might help visually show the nesting of this dataset, with the highlights indicating the parts I want to extract from each of the sublists (OFT_1 through OFT_4).

[Screenshot of TrackingAll List, showing the four main sublists (correspond to input csv files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ydl0.png)

[Expanded view of OFT_1 csv, showing the extent of the sublists, with the highlighted portions indicating the parts I'm trying to extract together.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92NEs.png)

Thanks!

Comment: check `Filter` to filter elements of lists

Comment: In your example, it is not clear what getElement does. But a possible solution could be: `lapply(TrackingAll, function(x) c(x$data$nose, x$data$median.data))`. However, if this is not what you were looking for, I suggest you repost your question using a simple reproducible example. I mean, a code where you create a complex list and show us what is your expected output.

Comment: A reproducible example would be lovely. All I can say otherwise is that `purrr::pluck()` might help you index into nested lists.

Comment: @WenchengLau-Medrano If you use the code from the DLCAnalyzer (readily available on Github), that will pull up the exact example of the complex list I'm trying to work it. I don't know how else to create such a multi-layered list example.

Comment: @WenchengLau-Medrano the 'getElement" part was from a suggested solution to a related problem, but does do what I want (creates a new list of just the data$nose elements). 

For your suggestion solution, it still only pulls out the sublist (TrackingAll$data$nose), but does not include the sublist TrackingData$median.data. I'm trying to put both into a new list.

Comment: @alyb_batgirl the problem is that your script is not quite easy to reproduce. Just look the ammount, specific versions and kind of packages that you are suggesting to install. It is more likely that someone in Stackoverflow will help you if you write a simple and specific reproducible example. In the other hand, it is more unlikely if you start your post asking for cloning and running a complex example from a repo and depeding of lots of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but realized I could just create separate lists and then recombine them.

So using the data from above (yes, I know, its not easy to reproduce, but if I knew how to replicate the complex list I'm trying to deal with, I probably wouldn't be here asking basic questions about lists).

```
test <- lapply(TrackingAll, getElement, c("data", "nose")) #this creates a new list of just the nose dataframes
test2 <- lapply(TrackingAll, getElement, "median.data") #this creates a separate list of the median data points for each input file
new_list <- list(data = test, median.data = test2) #create new list that has a sublist of all the nose dataframes (called data) and another sublist of all the median data points (named median. data)
```